# Why do people substitute "Way" for "Much"?

Tags: slang

Nowadays people often say "way more", "way better" etc. instead of using the word "much". How did this become popular usage?

Comment: My guess would be that the expression was originally "far and away more" or some such.  Regardless, the usage is well-established.

Comment: More likely, as @rogermue suggests, ***a** (long) way*, which refers to any linear scale of measurement, and shows up as _away, a (long) ways_, and even _a (long) ways away_. As an intensifier, it indicates that whatever's at the end of "the long way" is **significantly** more `X` than the thing on the other end, like a horse leading by several lengths.

Answer (score 3):

The forms "way more," "way better," and the like, in the sense of "far more," "far better," and so on, may go even farther back than Etymonline's dating (cited in bib's answer) suggests.

---

***Search results for ten phrases***

I ran Google Books searches for "is way above," "is way back," "is way behind," "is way better," "is way far," "is way more, "is way off," and "is way out," "is way too," and "is way up" for the period 1800–1950, with the following earliest-occurrence matches for each.

From [Testimony Taken Before the Canal Investigating Commission](https://books.google.com/books?id=qpE7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA427&dq=%22is+way+above%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VrTuVLSnI87coATj8ICgDA&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20above%22&f=false), sixth session (June 8, 1875), in *Documents of the Senate of the State of New York*, Volume 4 (1876):

> Q. How many chains is it between those two locks, 18 and 19?
>
> A. I don't know; lock 19 is **way above** the lower Mohawk.

From Thomas Norwood, [*Plutocracy: Or, American White Slavery*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7lYYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA312&dq=%22is+way+back%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G7DuVOb7C8rVoATLpILYDA&ved=0CEcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20back%22&f=false) (1888):

> "Second : the dead-line for a girl is farther back, higher up on this plane, than the dead-line for boys. It is **way back** beyond where you met the procession, Mr. Woolhat. " Third : When a girl once slips over that dead-line, both men and women drive her on, down, farther down, until she falls over into that pit, from which she can never rise.

From "[From the Pacific Coast](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yh8AAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA33&dq=%22is+way+behind%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=C5zuVMntB8rloASsjYDQBQ&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20behind%22&f=false)," in *The Clothier & Furnisher* (May 9, 1889):

> In the retail furnishings trade there is a noticeable improvement. A full month of as perfect weather as any reasonable being could ask for, has, of course, had a most beneficial effect on this line of goods. Even with this improvement they are making the same complaint as at this time last month to the effect that tho season is **way behind**, and that they cannot now make up for lost time.

From Harold Bindloss, [*Masters of the Wheat-Lands*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A6klAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA263&dq=%22is+way+better%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QqHuVLWZEM2vogSU0oCYAg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20better%22&f=false) (1910):

> "Then," Sally responded, "it is **way better** that you didn't marry him." She paused, and seemed to search for words with which to express herself. " I knew all along all there was to know about Gregory—except that he was going to marry you, and it was some time before I heard that—and I was ready to take him. I was fond of him."

From the [entry for December 26, 1888](https://books.google.com/books?id=7UNfv-kod0cC&pg=PA390&dq=%22is+way+far%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nrLuVNDnNdDWoATOloGICw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20far%22&f=false) in *With Walt Whitman in Camden*, volume 1 (1914):

> I was speaking of Emerson and W[hitman] as the giants of our time in America—the only giants. "I assume that you stand incomparably higher than all others." I said: "I think less of Bryant than probably you do." "I have an idea you do : I think a great deal of him : regard him highly : but I clearly perceive that you are essentially right — that taken all in all Emerson is **way, far, above** all others: not one to share his glory."

From U.S. Congress, [*Hearings of the House Select Committee to Investigate the Interstate Migration of Destitute Families*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0YAY2k77bE8C&q=%22is+way+more%22&dq=%22is+way+more%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LbnuVM3kJpXjoASChYH4Ag&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgK) (1940) [combined snippets]:

> Mr COOK. I kept going deeper and deeper from that day on, and then in 1934, when that drought hit us, there was no feed to be gotten, you just had to buy what you could get, and we paid as high as $21 for a load of oat straw.
>
> Mr. PARSONS. Yes.
>
> Mr. COOK. $21 a ton, which is **way more** than straw ever has been worth or ever will be. Well, then, after hay got way up there and lots of the alfalfa was pretty risky to buy, because they'd water it to keep the leaves on, and watered it too heavy. I have seen alfalfa that when a man went to cut the wires on the bale you couldn't get it loose with a crowbar.

From the [address of Mr. Green of Tennessee Conference](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZIUsAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA169&dq=%22is+way+off%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n5PuVJT6IIHxoATU64LQBg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20off%22&f=false) (May 26, 1844), in *Debates of the General Conference, of the Methodist Episcopal Church, May, 1844* (1845):

> Methodism has but one heart. Say you are sorry that Bishop Andrew is connected with slavery, but that you have no constitutional power to touch it, as he has violated no rule of discipline. Some of you can do this, you have told me so, that this would enable you to satisfy all that you know ; but the great difficulty is **way off** yonder, somebody has told you. Will you then cut down this beautiful tree because you hear it reported that some of the distant branches will fall off if you do not cut the tree down. Let me entreat you to do all you can to save the church.

From Arthur Morecamp, [*Live Boys: or Charley and Nasho in Texas*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7fNDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22is+way+out%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kqruVLq7JtHgoATljoKACw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20out%22&f=false) (1878):

> I ran into Auntie's room so out of breath I could hardly speak. "Oh, Uncle! the dogs have treed a great big panther, and Nasho is watching him : wont you take your gun and shoot him — quick Uncle, please, before he gets away. He run up the tree we was standing against and is **way out** on a top limb. Make haste Uncle, please.”

From Alfred Lewis, [*Wolfville*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WJkLv0dmrKkC&pg=PA155&dq=%22is+way+too%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Vq7uVKq4KMG7ogSfiICQBQ&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20too%22&f=false) (1897):

> 'Pass over them documents for Cherokee Hall, an' don't hold out nothin' onto us. We-alls is **'way too peevish** to stand any offishul gaieties to-day.'

From Massachusetts State Board of Agriculture, [*Annual Report of the Secretary of the Massachusetts State Board of Abriculture*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BxLOAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22is+way+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6LruVKCbPM-oogSAnIK4Aw&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22is%20way%20up%22&f=false) (1877):

> The rye is looking so finely, and I have so much confidence in my ability to to raise corn with these commercial fertilizers, that I have concluded to fence that piece of ground, and, in addition, another piece which I have ploughed up, and I propose to plant corn next year and manure it with commercial fertilizers, that I have concluded to fence that piece of ground, and, in addition, another piece which I have ploughed up, and I propose to plant corn next year, and manure it with chemical fertilizers, because it is **way up** on a hill,—although it is pretty flt when you get there,—so that you cannot haul manure up there, but you can take the fertilizers up on your back.

---

***Conclusions from these results***

The years of first occurrence for these ten expressions are, from earliest to latest, 1844 (*way off*), 1875 (*way above*), 1877 (*way up*), 1878 (*way out*), 1888 (*way back*), 1888 (*way far*), 1889 (*way behind*), 1897 (*way too*), 1910 (*way better*), and 1940 (*way more*). It seems safe to say that by the end of the 1870s, colloquial wordings in which way functioned as a synonym for *far* or *much* were well established in U.S. speech.

To generate a manageable number of results, I made *is* the first word of each search phrase, greatly reducing the number of matches for each phrase. It seems highly likely that even earlier matches for *way* used in the sense of *far* or *much* exist, in situations where *way* is not preceded by *is*.

The search results also seem to confirm Etymonline's remark that *way*, when used in this sense, is "short for away": On several occasions, early matches for the search phrase rendered *way* as the contracted form *'way* of *away*.

It appears that using *way* in place of *far* or *much* has been part of colloquial U.S. speech for 140 years or so, with one instance going back 170 years. The usage may be more frequent now than in the past, but it has been around for  very long time.

---

***Earlier matches from newspaper articles***

I limited my original answer to Google Books search results. Searches of the Elephind newspaper database yield earlier instances of some of the ten phrases noted above. They are as follows:

From "[Actors in Summer Time: How They Spend Their Vacation](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83032300/1882-07-28/ed-1/seq-4/#words=%22is%2Bway%2Bback%22)," originally printed in the *New York Sun*, reprinted in the *Lancaster [Pennsylvania] Daily Intelligencer* (July 28, 1882):

> "Frank Mayo is another instance of the desire to have a 'home,'" he continued affably. "When he had cleared his first $50,000 on *Davy Crockett* he went into the wilds of Pennsylvania and built a place he calls 'Crockett Lodge.' It is **way back** in an almost inaccessible point in the mountains, and when *Davy* goes there to spend his summers be almost dies of loneliness."

From "[Behind the Times](https://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=SJO18591005-02.2.22&e=-------en-20--1--img-txIN-%22is+way+behind%22---------)," in the *[Springfield, Illinois] Daily Journal* (October 5, 1859):

> The Register [a rival newspaper] flies the following from its mast head:
>
> DEMOCRATIC DOCTRINE in 1856—"The people of a territory, like those of a State, shall decide for themselves whether slavery shall or shall not exist within their limits.'—JAMES BUCHANAN.
>
> The Register is **way behind** the times. That may have been the Democratic doctrine in 1856, but the Dred Scott decision has been rendered, since then, and the doctrine now reads thus:
>
> "The Constitution of the United States recognizes slaves as property, and pledges the federal government to protect it.'—DRED SCOTT DECISION.

From an [untitled item](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/2010270501/1903-06-26/ed-1/seq-8/#words=%22is%2Bway%2Bbetter%22) in the *Alliance [Nebraska] Herald* (June 26, 1903):

> Mrs. Matilda Hood will sell eighty-five head of grade cattle at her ranch, notice of which appears elsewhere in this paper, next Tuesday, June 30, a 9:30 o'clock. The crowd should gather early to allow the sale to begin as early as possible. A free lunch will be given at noon. If you want some stock which is **way better** than the average, attend this sale. Stuff will all be disposed of to bona tide bidders according to terms of sale, as we understand it.

From "[Rally of the 'Old-Line Whigs of Virginia'](https://virginiachronicle.com/?a=d&d=RE18560722.1.1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22is+way+out%22-------)" in the *Richmond [Virginia] Enquirer* (July 22, 1856):

> After the convention of this Party had adjourned on Thursday last, a grand mass meeting was held on the Capitol Square, in this city, for the express purpose of exhibiting enthusiasm, or, as our friend of the Richmond *Examiner* used to have it, *Entoosymeem*." The Petersburg *Intelligencer* styles the metropolitan city "*Big Richmond*." and Old Line Whigs, when we were boys, need to be able to get up 'big meetings" in the big Gibraltar. But the New York *Tribune* styles Richmond an out-of-the-way place, too small and insignificant for Crawford's equestrian statue of Washington even to he placed in it, and as the old settlers of former days used to say of the far West, "it is **way out** back."—This no doubt will account in a measure for the scene which occurred at this enthusiastic gathering.

From "[Minor Mention](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn99021999/1886-12-18/ed-1/seq-6/#words=%22is%2Bway%2Btoo%22)," in the *Omaha [Nebraska] Daily Bee* (December 18, 1886):

> Before being caught by the advertised "less than cost" racket on Christmas slippers call at Adams', 417 Broadway, Council Bluffs, and find out the fact that some dealers COST price is **'way too** high.

From "[A Political Joke](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=IA18550601.1.1&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22is+way+up%22------)" in the *[Brookville] Indiana American* (June 1, 1855):

> In a neighboring county, one of the political parties for over twenty years had been in the nabit of holding their county nominating conventions at the house of Mr. G——. He happened on a recent occasion, ofr the first time, to be in when they had finished their business, and heard a little delegate from R. move that this convention adjourn *sine die*. "Sine die!" said Mr. G——, to a person standing near, where is that?" "Why, that is **way up** in the northern part of the county," said his neighbor? "Hold on, if you please, Mr. *Cheerman*," said G——, with great earnestness and emphasis; "hold on, sir, I'd like to be heard on that question. I have kept public house for more than twenty years. I am a poor man. I have always belonged to the party, and never split a ticket in my life.—This is the most central location in the county, and its where we've allers held our caucuses. I have never had or asked an office, and have worked night and day for the party, and now I think, sir, it is contemptible to go adjourning this convention ***way up** to sine die*!"

These earlier occurrences of several phrases involving way as an intensifier alter the order of first occurrence that I noted in my original answer. The order for the ten expressions, from earliest to latest, now runs as follows: 1844 (*way off*), 1855 (*way up*, Indiana) 1856 (*way out*, Virginia), 1859 (*way behind*, Illinois), 1875 (*way above*), 1882 (*way back*, Pennsylvania), 1886 (*way too*, Nebraska), 1888 (*way far*), 1903 (*way better*, Nebraska), and 1940 (*way more*). Even when limiting the pool of search terms to those prefaced by "is," I have now confirmed instances of four of the ten phrases using *way* as an intensifier from before 1860.

One particularly interesting instance is the occurrence of "is 'way too high" from Nebraska in 1886. This suggests that *way* may have emerged in this usage not as a short form of "a long way" but as a truncation of *away*. Either way, the term seems to have emerged first in the context of distances and only later come to be applied to situations (such as "way better") where *way* might be understood as a short form of "in every way."

Answer (score 2):

*Etymonline* offers this commentary for the use of *[way](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=way&searchmode=none)* as an adverb

> c.1200, short for away (adv.). Many expressions involving this are modern and American English colloquial, such as way-out "far off;" way back "a long time ago" (1887); way off "quite wrong" (1892). Any or all of these might have led to the slang adverbial meaning "very, extremely," attested by 1984 (as in way cool).

Answer (score 1):

"That was way back in the forties when I was young."

Here "way back" means "a long way back". The image of soldiers marching a long way back is transferred to time, a long march back in time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Metaphor Theme; in this case, [Life is a Journey](https://justinrossow.com/2011/09/05/life-is-a-journey/). In this theme, people's lives are cognized as movement along a path from birth to death. It's memorialized in such expressions as

- *She's going through a very rough patch right now.*
- *I never thought I'd have so much trouble reaching this point in my career*.

*Way* fits in to this theme as a marking for the path that one takes, or should take. If you *lose your way*, you're not following the proper path on your journey. *Way* features in many fixed phrases and idioms, like *going my way, the way of all flesh, that's the way to go, all the way back,* etc.

Used as an intensifier, like *much*, *way* is short for *a long way* (a short way wouldn't get commented on) along some scale, treated as a path. Try substituting *a long way* for *way* in such contexts:

- *That's (a long) way more than I was expecting.*
- *That tastes (a long) way better than this does.*

And note that both examples are comparatives (*more* and *better*).
Is this part of the construction?